# running a bash script in salt-minions

Tags: salt-stack

I am using CentOS -7 and it has latest Salt installed(salt 2017.7.2 (Nitrogen).  I want to execute a certain script in all the salt-minions connected from salt-master and provide me the exit status from the salt-minions so that I can determine the salt states would be declared pass or fail.
Below are the contents of init.sls contents. Can anyone help me in this regard please? If you provide me some example code that would really help.

Regards
Pradeep

Note: There i tried to post code but stackoverflow is giving errors for improper indentation.

**First attempt**

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.script

Then I tried jinja way after googling around a bit:

**Second Attempt**

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/salt-users/IJo6Z8Hro2w

```
Rendering SLS 'base:abcd' failed: Problem running salt function in Jinja template: Unable to run command '['/root/scripts/test.sh']' with the context '{'timeout': None, 'with_communicate': True, 'shell': False, 'bg': False, 'stderr': -2, 'env': {'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'LC_NUMERIC': 'C', 'NOTIFY_SOCKET': '/run/systemd/notify', 'LC_MESSAGES': 'C', 'LC_IDENTIFICATION': 'C', 'LC_MONETARY': 'C', 'LC_COLLATE': 'C', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C', 'LC_ADDRESS': 'C', 'LC_MEASUREMENT': 'C', 'LC_TELEPHONE': 'C', 'LC_PAPER': 'C', 'LC_NAME': 'C', 'PATH': '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin', 'LC_TIME': 'C'}, 'stdout': -1, 'close_fds': True, 'stdin': None, 'cwd': '/root'}', reason: command not found; line 1
```

Comment: could you post your `init.sls` contents ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I run scripts on my SaltStack install:

```
run_my_script.sh:
  cmd.script:
    - name: my_script.sh
    - source: salt://scripts/my_script.sh
```

You can then just check the exit status of the state.